# Do variables dimensions matter in PID simulation + I want the PID output to be volts?

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, pid-control

I have a self balancing robot control loop that uses the PID controller. I feed the robot's angle (rad) to sum block that generates the error between the set point and the angle.

The error then goes to the PID and goes to DC motor block that needs the input to be in volts and generate an output in N.m.  Then the signal goes to the self balancing robot block that need the input to be in N.m and outputs a rad angle.
[image]
As you see I don't know how to make the PID output a voltage (V). How i can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PID simulation you've built does not care about the units of numbers being passed around your control loop.  However, you may want to ensure that the units are correct at different points in the loop to make it easier for you to interpret and debug.  To do that, you can simply add gain blocks (no frequency dependence) with the appropriate conversion factors.  If you do not add separate gain blocks, then the unit conversion will be implicitly included in the gain of each transfer function.

Comment: thank you very much this was helpful